# Play! 2.1.1 framework javascript in template causes compile error

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

I just started working with the play framework.  Loving it except Im having trouble with the view templates.

Whenever I include javascript directly on the view template, I get a compile error.  Is this not possible with  play! templating?

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script>

function isEmpty(obj) {
    //for(var prop in obj) {
    //if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
    try{
      if(JSON.stringify(obj)=='{}'){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }catch(e){
      return false;
    }
  }

</script>
```

I get the error "Not Parsed?"   on the line with function isEmpty(obj) {

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's an example javascript that results in a compile error?

Comment: Please provide sample code and the specific compilation error that you are receiving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you are commenting JavaScript line with `//` for template's parser bracket is a special char:

```
//for(var prop in obj) {
```

In general, brackets in Scala templates has special meaning, so building advanced JavaScripts directly in the view causes many problems. You need to still control if new *innocent* change in JS doesn't brake template parser, or vice versa - if template parser doesn't devastate your scripts. Simplest solution is just separating JS from the view, you have two solutions and I think that first is better:

1. Save your JS into common `*.js` file and include it with `<script src...>` tag. If you need to pass some data from your view, use global JS var first:

   ```
   <script>var helloMessage = "Welcome on page @title";</script> 
   <script src="/path/to/your.js"></script>
   ```
2. Read the content of JS `file` (not Scala template!) in your controller and pass as a `String` to the view, you will need to escape it with `Html()`:

   ```
   @(title: String, mySpecialJS: String)(content: Html)
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <title>@title</title>
           @Html(mySpecialJS)
       </head>
   <body>
   ```
3. You can also join both approaches, for an example if you want to pass o complex object to the JavaScript depending on the controller/view elements, you can also build a `JSON` object in controller, convert it to `String` and then include JS with common tag:

   ```
   @(title: String, myJsConfig: String)(content: Html)
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <title>@title</title>
           <script>var myJsConfig = @Html(myJsConfig)</script> 
           <script src="/path/to/your.js"></script>
       </head>
   <body>
   ```

So finally in `your.js` you can use them as usually:

```
alert(helloMessage);
console.log("Config is...");
console.log(myJsConfig);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  I tried out these techniques and they worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The error is actually not at the `isEmpty()` line.

If you look at the Play Console the compiler output is pointing to a different place:

```
! @6e12h60d9 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

sbt.PlayExceptions$TemplateCompilationException: Compilation error[Not parsed?]
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$43.apply(PlayCommands.scala:433) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$43.apply(PlayCommands.scala:409) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf5$1.apply(Structure.scala:581) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf5$1.apply(Structure.scala:581) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311) ~[na:na]
[warn] play - No application found at invoker init
[error] C:\Users\maba\Development\play\layout\app\views\main.scala.html:14: Compilation error[Not parsed?]
[error]             //for(var prop in obj) {
[error]                               ^
[error] (compile:sources) @6e12hd81d: Compilation error in C:\Users\maba\Development\play\layout\app\views\main.scala.html:14
[error] application -
```

So there seems to be an error parsing the comments (don't know why at the moment).

So if you want this code to run just use Play comments (`@* some comment *@`) instead:

```js
<script>

  function isEmpty(obj) {
    @*
    for(var prop in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
    *@
    try{
      if(JSON.stringify(obj)=='{}'){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }catch(e){
      return false;
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  It was definitely the javascript comments that were causing me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function isEmpty(obj) {
    try{
  if(JSON.stringify(obj)=='{}'){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}catch(e){
  return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Please give an explanation of your answer along with the code.

Answer (score 0):

As @biesior described in the second point, `@Html()` prints code (html/js) from controller. 
But we are able to compile it without passing as parameter:

```
@Html(new String(
    """
    <script>

    </script>
    """)
)
```